# Splitting string before adding into an array

Tags: php, arrays

IM currently pulling some text and adding it into an array like so:

```
    foreach($getthesp2 as $thesp)
            {
        //  $sp[] = $thesp->textContent;
            $sp[] =      $thesp->textContent;

        }
```

The current output is like this:

> The SP is Bubbly Bailey (5/2), Burnt Cream (4/1), Pearl Noir (5/1),
>   Quality Art (6/1), Warm Order (8/1), Imaginary Diva (10/1), Nelson's
>   Pride (12/1), Trending (12/1), Senora Lobo (25/1), ? The SP is Mossgo
>   (7/2), Aaranyow (4/1), Ecliptic Sunrise (5/1), First Rebellion (6/1),
>   Incomparable (7/1), Go Charlie (8/1), Live Dangerously (12/1),
>   Studfarmer (12/1), Purford Green (16/1),

what i need it to do is take the string and break it up by , then add it into the array so the output would be:

> The SP is Bubbly Bailey (5/2) The SP is Burnt Cream (4/1) The SP is Pearl Noir (5/1),....

Comment: What's wrong with `explode()`?

Comment: Try to use $sp= explode(',',$thesp->textContent); Hope this help you

Comment: i tried the above and the output is The SP is Array? The SP is Array? The SP is Array? T

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map();`

```
$sp = array("The SP is Bubbly Bailey (5/2)", "Burnt Cream (4/1)", "Pearl Noir (5/1)", "Quality Art (6/1)", "Warm Order (8/1)", "Imaginary Diva (10/1)", "Nelson's Pride (12/1)", "Trending (12/1)", "Senora Lobo (25/1)", "? The SP is Mossgo (7/2)"," Aaranyow (4/1)", "Ecliptic Sunrise (5/1)"," First Rebellion (6/1)", "Incomparable (7/1)", "Go Charlie (8/1)", "Live Dangerously (12/1)"," Studfarmer (12/1)", "Purford Green (16/1)");

function add_string($sp)
{
    // clean string
    $sp = str_replace("? The SP is ", '', $sp);
    $sp = str_replace("The SP is ", '', $sp);
    // concatenation
        return("The SP is ".$sp);
}
$sp_new = array_map("add_string", $sp);
print_r($sp_new);
```

Comment: How should that help? Please add some more description…

Answer (score 0):

```
    $tags = explode(',',$new);

foreach($tags as $key) {    
    if ($key !== "")
        {$sp[] = $key;}

}
```

I did the above to solve me issue.